# PrimeNG Dropdown as a child in custom input - some problems

Tags: angular, input, dropdown, angular-reactive-forms, primeng

I am trying to create my own input component with reactive forms, in which I will have some various input types, where one of 'em would be PrimeNG Dropdown.

Currently, I am struggling with 3 cases:

1. dropdown selects first value by itself, where:
   form control value in service is undefined - OK
   _value in my own input component is undefined - OK
   ddValue is set to first options value - BAD
2. firing (change) function set as a attribute parameter in my own input component
3. passing PrimeNG Dropdown templates from my own input component to dropdown

someService.ts

```
 selectedCloth = this.fb.group({
        cloth: new FormControl<Cloth|undefined>(undefined)
    });
```

parent.component.html

```
            <form [formGroup]="someService.selectedCloth">
                <app-my-own-input formControlName="cloth"
                                inputType="dropdown"
                                [options]="someService.someOptions"
                                optionLabel="clothName"
                                placeholder="Select stuff"
                                (change)="getClothCost()">
                </app-my-own-input>
            </form>
```

my-own-input.component.html

```
<p-dropdown [inputId]="'clothDropdown'"
            [name]="'clothDropdown'"
            [options]="options"
            [optionLabel]="optionLabel"
            [(ngModel)]="ddValue"
            [placeholder]="placeholder"
            [showClear]="false"
            (onChange)="dropdownChanged($event.value)">
// HERE I NEED TO PLACE TWO TEMPLATES FOR SELECTED ITEM AND ITEM
</p-dropdown>
```

my-own-input.component.ts

```
import {
    ChangeDetectorRef,
    Component,
    ContentChild,
    ElementRef,
    EventEmitter,
    forwardRef,
    Injector,
    Input,
    OnInit,
    Output,
    Self, TemplateRef
} from '@angular/core';
import {ControlValueAccessor, FormControl, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, NgControl} from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-form-input',
    templateUrl: './form-input.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./form-input.component.scss'],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
            multi: true,
            useExisting: FormInputComponent
        }
    ]
})
export class FormInputComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {
    @Input() placeholder: string = '';
    @Input() inputType: string | undefined;
    @Input() dataType: string | undefined;
    @Input() options: any;
    @Input() optionLabel: any;
    ddValue: any = undefined;

    @Input('value') _value: any = undefined;
    @Input() disabled = false;
    onChange = (value: any) => {};
    onTouched = () => {
    };

    dropdownChanged(value: any) {
        this.value = value; // this one works, but (change) function in my-own-input is 
                               not fired
    }

    get value() {
        return this._value;
    }

    set value(value) {
        this._value = value;
        this.onChange(value);
        this.onTouched();
        this.cd.detectChanges();
    }

    constructor(
        private cd: ChangeDetectorRef
    ) {
    }

    writeValue(value: any) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
        this.onChange = fn;
    }

    registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
        this.onTouched = fn;
    }

    setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean) {
        this.disabled = isDisabled;
    }
 
    ngOnInit(): void {

    }

}
```

piece of dropdown template I want to pass, where it must be a universal thing, because object keys can vary and key nesting can also vary

```
<ng-template pTemplate="selectedItem">
    <div>{{ someService.selectedCloth.controls.cloth.value?.clothName }}</div>
</ng-template>
<ng-template let-oneCloth pTemplate="item">
    <div [class]="!oneCloth.id ? 'grey-text' : ''">
        {{ oneCloth.clothname }}
    </div>
</ng-template>
```